# gSOAP C++: nillable attributes

Tags: c++, gsoap

how is it possible to set the xsi:nil="true" attribute on only single elements? With the runtime-flag "SOAP_XML_NIL" I will set it globally, so it affects every attribute.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To add `xsi:nil="true"` automatically to the XML payload when a class/struct member is NULL, you will only need to annotate the member as required (with a `1`):

```
class ns__some_data
{
   public:
     int *some_member 1; // nillable pointer & element is marked as required
};
```

When setting `ns__some_data::some_member = NULL`, the XML will have the `xsi:nil` attribute, which is what I think you want:

```
<ns:some-data>
  <some-member xsd:nil="true"/>
</ns:some-data>
```

To make sure this works as expected, you will need to upgrade to the latest version of gSOAP (2.8.28 or later).